# Calculating Time complexity for a transpose matrix

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

The code is a summarized version of a piece of code trying to transpose a matrix. My task for this is to find the time complexity of this program.

[image]

I am only interested in the time complexity for the number of swaps that occur. I found out that on the outer loop for the swapping it occurs n-1 times and as for the inner loop it occurs (n^2 -n)/2 times.

---

I derived these solutions by subst n with a number.

- When n=4, my inner loop would loop 1+2+3 times
- When n=5, my inner loop would loop 1+2+3+4 times
- Therefore innerloop=(n^2 - n) / 2

How would i calculate the time complexity of this code?

---

I saw somewhere online where the person just took the values from his innerloop count and determine it was a O(n) complexity.

---

[Edit]
Do i need to cater in the other loops to calculate the time complexity as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your swap algorithm is a clear `(1+2+3+...n)` case, which [translates to](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-for-formula-for-sum-of-sequence-123-ldotsn) n×(n+1)/2.

Since constants and lower degree parts of a calculation don't count in Big O notation, this translates to `O(n^2)`.

Taking in the other loops, won't change your time complexity, since they are also O(n^2). In terms of Big O, it doesn't make sense to write `O(3(n^2))`, because constants are dropped.

But what could help you here is that you don't need to bother with the more complex swap for loop. (I don't mean when you're learning. I mean, when you're dealing with real-world problems.)

On a side note, I would recommend reading *example 3* of the *Big O* section in **Cracking the Coding Interview (6th edition) (2015)** by - McDowell, Gayle, which addresses this exact situation and many similar ones.